# iptables INPUT command

Tags: iptables, firewall

On a machine called ubuntu1, this is the `iptables` command:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP`

on the other computer (xp1) I can not ping the ubuntu1.So this is OK.
But On ubuntu1 **can** ping xp1. and I think this is not OK. I do not have problem with ping request but I have problem with ping replay from xp1. Why does that command not drop the replay of ping which is an ICMP packet?

**UPDATE:**

I did a mistake . I did not see the replay on terminal!!! I just see the replay on wireshark.!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command which you are entering is just for blocking incoming ICMP connection if you want to block outgoing ICMP connection you have to choose output chain 
i.e

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j DROP`